# How to import contents of text file into mysql table in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've searched different forums on this one, but still no luck.
I have tried different codes, so far my query looks like this:

```
Dim query As String
query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\swipeimport\A1_20130513.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_entrance_swipe (@var1)" & _
           "SET Loc=SUBSTRING(@var1,1,3)," & _
           "date=SUBSTRING(@var1,4,8)," & _
           "time=SUBSTRING(@var1,12,3)," & _
           "temp=SUBSTRING(@var1,16,3)," & _
           "id=SUBSTRING(@var1,19,10);"
    con.Open()

    Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, con)

    Dim i As Integer = sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Record is Successfully Inserted")
    Else
        MsgBox("Record is not Inserted")
    End If
    con.Close()
```

I want to import the contents of a text file into table, my table has this fields:

```
Loc, date, time, temp, id.
```

The content of the text file looks like this:

```
K0720130514045501018006D9566
```

where the breakdown is as follows:

```
K07        ----> Loc
20130514   ----> date
0455       ----> time
010        ----> temp
18006D9566 ----> id
```

could you help, i cannot insert this in my table. What is the problem with my code?
It just give a fatal error. Please point me in the right direction. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is my connection string:

```
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=dev;Database=mydb;User ID=root;Password=mypass;")
```

Comment: it might also help people to see your connection string

Comment: would it be performance wise if i store the lines of text as lists? then do the substring?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you....

```
        Dim filename As String = "C:\swipeimport\A1_20130513.txt"
        Dim Query As String
        Dim data As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename)
        Dim Loc, _date, time, temp, id As String
        Loc = data.Substring(0, 3)
        _date = data.Substring(3, 8)
        time = data.Substring(11, 4)
        temp = data.Substring(15, 3)
        id = data.Substring(18, 9)
        Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_entrance_swipe VALUES ('" + Loc + "','" + _date + "','" + time + "','" + temp + "','" + id + "')"
        Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=dev;Database=mydb;User ID=root;Password=mypass;")
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
            sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record is Successfully Inserted")
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            con.Close()
            MsgBox("Record is not Inserted" + ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: it doesn't insert all lines in my text file. it only inserts the first line...do i have to reiterate to all lines?

Comment: what should i do in order to reiterated over the lines?

Comment: i have stored the lines of texts as lists, is it performance wise?